# Creating a parallelograme in c#

Tags: c#, do-while

My goal is to make a parallelogram with "do while" loop(s). It needs to be as long and wide as the user says. 
 Baisically if user says that the side should be 5, the outcome would have to look like this: 
 ***** 
 ***** 
 *****
*****
*****
 What I came up with was this code, which will unfortunatly give me just the first row of all the stars I need.

```
        Console.Write("How long should the side of this parallelogram be? ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int side = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        int j = 0;
        int l = 0; 

        do
        {
        if (j < side){
        Console.Write("*");
            j++;
        }
        if (j >= side){
        Console.Write("\n");
          l++;
        }
        }
       while (l < side) ;


        Console.ReadKey();
```

I believe that this is a fairly simple problem, but I am a big time programmer newbie and I'm out of ideas on what else I can try. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Although a square is a parallelogram, you are in fact trying to produce [squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square). And you should check your [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset the i variable after you finish a line:

```
            int i = 0, current_line = 0;

            do
            {
                if (i < side)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");

                    i = 0;
                    current_line++;
                }
            } while (current_line < side);
```

As a little notice, that is a square ;)

Comment: No, it is a square ;-)

Comment: And a parallelogramme.

Comment: And a diamond... etc.

Comment: And a first draft of a circle.

Answer (score 4):

The most understandable way to accomplish a 2D structure is using 2 nested loops.
One loops creates each `*` of the row, and the other repeats the rows.

I find this more readable than `do/while` loops for this purpose.

```
for (int j = 0; j < side; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < side; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Btw, this is a square.

---

Here's a shorter version exploiting an overload of the `string` constructor:

```
string row = new string('*', side); //create a string containing 'side' repetitions of '*'
for (int i = 0; i < side; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row); //WriteLine will add the '\n' for you.
}
```

Comment: I understand, but part of my assignment was to make it only with do/while and exactly without "for".

Still, thank you for your explanation and even the fact that you took time to read and answer this.

Comment: Sure. Btw, if your assignment is to "create a parallelogram" then I would assume you're supposed to add `X` or `side-X` spaces before each row, where `X` is the current line number.

Answer (score 1):

```
int side = Convert.ToInt32(input);
int j = 0;
int l = 0; 
do
{
  do 
  {
    Console.Write("*");
    j++;    
  }while(j< side);
j = 0;
Console.Write("\n");  
l++;
}while(l < side);
```